# Nuget package manager for SP 2010 SharePoint.Client.dll - CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, development, csom

I need to access the SharePoint 2010 site's splist information with attachments.  am having VS 2015 installed my VM.

Is there any way to get the nuget package thats suitable for accessing the SP 2010 CSOM dll ? [ i want to use CSOM with C# ]
I don't have access to admin privileges to the VM. So, I cant install the CSOM SDK 
in the VM.

Can anyone please throw some light on this nuget package if it exists.And if not, whats the alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the nuget manager in Visual Studio search for **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime**:

[image]

There is a good chance that **Microsoft.SharePoint2013.CSOM** nuget package will be somewhat compatible with SharePoint 2010 and still work just fine.

Comment: This is missing the Utility package (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.aspx). Any idea how to get these 2 to play along together?