# Copy Sharepoint list into Sql table

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-foundation, sql-query

I am having the task to copy the data of a Sharepoint list into the three different sql tables.
[image]

Sql table details are:

**cLetterSection**

```
SectionID(Identity column)

SectionLanguage(depends on image header if "section" then English, if "section_1031" then German)

SectionName(section column value will be populated here)
```

**cLetterConfig**

```
ConfigID(Identity column)

Language(depends on image header if "section" then English, if "section_1031" then German)

SectionID(foreign key from cLetterTemplate table)

Option(option column value will be populated here)
```

**cLetterReasonRel**

```
ConfigID(foreign key from cLetterConfig table)

CancellationReasonGroupCode(applicableTo column value will be populated here)
```

Actually I am the new in this area, could any one suggests how to do this.

Comment: what is the SharePoint version 2010 or 2013& above ?

Comment: It has Sharepoint version 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can **CSOM** or **SSOM** to fulfill you requirement

You can create a console app to copy the data from the sharepoint lists to SQL  tables. Please userSharePoint 2010 CSOM dll as mentioned in the [Nuget package manager for SP 2010 SharePoint.Client.dll - CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/239236/nuget-package-manager-for-sp-2010-sharepoint-client-dll-csom) for this purpose

please check the below for the reference

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/31f2fd7d-ff7b-4fe1-95a1-4070b96068cb/programmatically-insert-list-items-to-sql-server-table?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: I am not getting any thing.